# What is the best way to communicate from Angular2 to Electron and back?

Tags: node.js, typescript, angular, electron

I have this simple app (Node.js, Electron, Angular2, TypeScript) like you can find in any tutorial.

What is the best way to communicate from Angular2 to Electron and back?

Let's say you want to call a [system dialog](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/dialog.md). How would you do that?

These are my main source files:

- [My main Electron file](http://pastie.org/10760989)
- [My main Angular2 index](http://pastie.org/10760987)
- [My Angular2 bootstrap file](http://pastie.org/10760990)
- [My Angular2 root component](http://pastie.org/10761001)

Comment: Seriously, is someone just running through all new questions and voting to close them as off-topic? How is this off topic? Knock it off.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you wanna say with your comment.

Comment: Oh I was just complaining about the individual who voted to close your question as "off topic" when your question is clearly not off topic. There were several other questions this happened to as well. Yours was the third I had seen in the span of ten minutes so clearly somebody was just going through and voting to close new questions without even seriously looking at them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can treat the main Electron file like a server running in node. Meaning you can communicate with it any way you choose.

- You can spin up an express http server and create some API endpoints to hit from your Angular code on the client-side.
- You could fire up a socket.io server and use a websocket for communication.
- You can also just straight up use those APIs right inside your angular code if you don't care about mixing system code with client-side code. Only do this if your app will always be an Electron app and never ported to a web app. If it's ever going to be a web app then your client-side Angular app should stick to using only font-end javascript code and let the main Electron file act as a server.

Comment: +1 for socket.io. Using it exactly this way for an Electron app i'm currently working on. With any server, and especially websockets, keep in mind that anything (like a webpage open in a browser) would be able to connect unless some kind of authentication is implemented.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to go is communicate using ipc events. Use ipcRenderer on browser side and ipcMain on the Electron side. That's pretty much what I have done in my app (work in progress) https://github.com/sumitkm/electricedit/

However I used KO not Angular.

Comment: Yes, I stumbled upon that too. [That's what you mean](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/ipc-main.md), right?

Comment: Yup... you can setup a custom queue kind of pattern where UI raises events and electron responds to the events once done... can get a bit clunky but I am still trying things out :-)...